# Trouble passing ruby to javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm having trouble passing a ruby array to jquery in Rails 2.3. What are best practices for passing ruby data to jquery? Below I am trying to write a bit of jquery that responds to rails controllers and controller actions.

```
  <% action_array = [params[:controller], params[:action]] %>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() { 

      var path =  <%= action_array.to_json %>;

        if ( path[0] == "home" ) {
    $('.home').addClass('gradientBGRed');
}

});

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="headerNav" class="gradientBG">
<li class="home "><a href="/">Home </a></li>
<% if logged_in? %>
  <li class="register "><a href="/account">Account </a></li>
 <li class="login last"><a href="<%= logout_path %>">log out </a></li>
  <% else %>
  <li class="register "><a href="/customers/new">register </a></li>
    <li class="login last "><a href="<%= login_path %>">log in </a></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at the RailsCast about [Passing data to JavaScript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) ;)

Comment: did u try var path =  "<%= action_array.to_json %>"; or var path = "#{action_array.to_json}";

Comment: @Raghu: this is not neccessary because the `to_json` method already includes quotes to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is something wrong with your selector

`$('.home').addClass('gradientBGRed');`

the dot is important because it is a class you are search for

Comment: Apologies for the typo, but it doesn't work even with the $('.home') selector

Comment: mhh, try `$(document).ready( function() {` instead of `$(document).ready( function {`

Comment: Ok $(document).ready( function() { solves the first problem, I can now execute jquery within the curly braces (i.e. alert("HEY!") works etc) but it's still not adding the class.

Comment: which curly braces? the ones of the function or the ones of the if?

Comment: Actually nevermind. It works after correcting to function() . Thanks!